# How to recreate ASP encryption function in a script?

Tags: asp.net, bash, powershell, encryption, scripting

I currently have an ASP web application that amongst other things, performs encryption on a string. I would like to utilize this encryption function outside of my application to encrypt a set of strings. I need to utilize the same encryption function because these encrypted strings will be inserted into the application's database and decrypted within the application.

**Q:** Is it possible to write a powershell script to utilize the ASP encryption function? If not, what are the correct "tools" that would be needed to read a set of strings and encrypt them in the same way the ASP application would, so that they can be decrypted by the application later on?

Encryption Function:

```
Function Encrypt(pwd)
    Dim key
    key = "_-#{[}]|!`~>(-<+"

    Dim strRet
    Dim nStrLen
    nStrLen = Len(pwd)
    Dim n
    For n = 1 To nStrLen
        strRet = strRet & Chr(Asc(Mid(pwd, n, 1)) Xor Asc(Mid(key, n, 1)))
    Next

    Encrypt = strRet
End Function
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to utilize *that* encryption method? Seems like it's not very robust. It's best not to implement your own stuff when it comes to security, but to use something that's been proven and tested.

Comment: I have adopted the application and at the moment cannot change the encryption function. @mason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of options.

First, you can migrate that script function into a .NET CLR language such as C# or VB, then package that function into an assembly. You can then call that assembly from a Powershell script, using the add-type cmdlet.

```
Add-Type -Path c:\path\myAssembly.dll
```

Second, you can actually take the C# or VB.NET converted source and integrate it directly into a Powershell script with a variation on add-type, with the -TypeDefinition switch pointing to a local variable containing the source text (totally untested example):

```
$mySource=@"public class psdemo{
              public int somevalue(){
                  return 100;
              }
          }"@
Add-Type -TypeDefinition $mySource
[psdemo]::somevalue()
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I'll look into implementing one of these solutions. Are there simpler ways of achieving this if powershell wasn't a requirement? Or would you use powershell regardless?

Comment: Why not just write the function directly in PowerShell? Why go through a CLR language first?

Comment: Thanks, hope they work out for you. If you're needing these strings to be decrypted in a support/admin type environment, then yes, Powershell would probably be the route I'd take. I surely thing PS is the direction Microsoft is trying to get people to pursue rather than script-based solutions using older languages like vbscript.

Comment: Certainly could, @briantist, but seemed the migrated code option might more closely fit his needs in terms of what he already had done. Good option, though.